# trait bound pallet::Config not satisfied even it is implemented

Tags: mock, config, tight-coupling

*If more context is needed, it is available in commit [b392cfa3, file `mock.rs`](https://git.duniter.org/nodes/rust/duniter-v2s/-/blob/b392cfa34945c5d74f0840e04c431dfec60e1418/pallets/quotas/src/mock.rs)*.

---

I'm trying to add a mock for my pallet `pallet_quotas` in order to implement unit tests.
My pallet depends on a certain configuration of `frame_system` which is:

```rust
impl system::Config for Test {
    // [...]
    type AccountData = pallet_duniter_account::AccountData<Balance, IdtyId<Test>>`
}
```

Thus, my mock depends on pallet `pallet_duniter_account` which is strongly coupled to my pallet `pallet_quotas` (
`pub trait Config: /* [...] */ + pallet_quotas::Config`). No problem, I'm also providing a `Config` implementation for this pallet in my mock:

```rust
impl Config for Test {
    type RuntimeEvent = RuntimeEvent;
    type ReloadRate = ReloadRate;
    type MaxQuotas = MaxQuotas;
}
```

But when I `cargo check --tests -p pallet-quotas`, I get the following:

```rust
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Test: pallet_quotas::pallet::Config` is not satisfied
   --> pallets/quotas/src/mock.rs:122:41
    |
122 | impl pallet_duniter_account::Config for Test {
    |                                         ^^^^ the trait `pallet_quotas::pallet::Config` is not implemented for `Test`
    |
note: required by a bound in `pallet_duniter_account::Config`
   --> /home/hugo/dev/duniter-v2s/pallets/duniter-account/src/lib.rs:67:11
    |
61  |     pub trait Config:
    |               ------ required by a bound in this trait
...
67  |         + pallet_quotas::Config
    |           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `Config`
    = note: `Config` is a "sealed trait", because to implement it you also need to implement `pallet_quotas::pallet::Config`, which is not accessible; this is usually done to force you to use one of the provided types that already implement it
```

which is annoying because I *did* provide an implementation of this trait.

---

I would like to clarify that I already have a valid runtime (`gdev`) which can run as well as integration tests for this runtime. But I really would like to have mocks and unit tests to be able to test more easily values for `ReloadRate` and `MaxQuotas` different than the one from `gdev` runtime.

This might be a pure Rust question, but the context of substrate makes me unsure about what the problem really is. As the compiler note states, `Config` would be a "sealed trait" even defined as `pub`.

Comment: The scope of these unit tests should be strictly limited to the pallet direct dependencies. All tests linked to indirect dependencies should go to integration tests.